# How do I copy text inside of the tooltip that appears when hovering over elements?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to set min and max dimensions for some elements on a webpage and for elements near the end of the screen, the tooltip is cut off. Usually I would just look at the computed height and width and guess what it could be rounded to, but the width and height are set to auto.

I can't change the size of the viewport, since the size of most of my elements is dependent on viewport width.

I could try to copy the text inside of the tooltip, but I don't know how to get it to stay frozen in place so that I can select the text.

I saw some answers saying to hold F8, but that only works if you have a tooltip applied to the element you're hovering over, it doesn't freeze the inspect tooltip.

[An example of what I'm trying to describe.


Source: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-75/#A%20detailed%20tooltip.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHUce.png)

Comment: If it's the standard tooltip then it's in `title` attribute of the element.

Comment: I tried to add an example of what I'm describing since I'm not sure what you think it is.

Comment: It's a built-in devtools overlay not a part of the page so its contents isn't selectable.

Comment: Ahhh... Is there anything else I could do? I'm working in Code.org and the document display isn't apart of the website itself, so that might be why the tooltip gets cut off by the wrapper.